# How to remove @prefix from field type when generating code with CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I create field member like this:

```
var fieldMember = new CodeMemberField("int", "Test");
```

Now because field type is "int" which is reserved C# keyword generated code looks like this:

```
@int Test;
```

Which does not compile.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using either

```
var fieldMember = new CodeMemberField("System.Int32", "Test");
```

Or

```
var fieldMember = new CodeMemberField(typeof(int), "Test");
```

Comment: was just about to post this :)

Comment: @nefarel "System.Byte[]" or typeof(byte[])